# undefined response from axios.post

Tags: api, react-native, react-redux, axios

when i try to make a post request i get a network error, with an error.message of 'undefined'

here's the setup:

```
    export default axios.create({
   baseURL: API_HOST,
   withCredentials: true,
   crossdomain: true,


  });
```

and the actual call:

```
export const Login = (email, password) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post('/v1/login?', {email, password})
    .then(response => {
      console.log('yes');
      token = () => {
        return response.token ? response.token : '';
      };
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_AUTH_PROPS,
        payload: [
          {prop: 'errorMessage', value: 'successed'},
          {prop: 'token', value: token},
        ],
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      debugger;
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_AUTH_PROPS,
        payload: [{prop: 'errorMessage', value: error.message}],
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: what are you getting in response? likeafter .then you have printed yes, try printing response

Comment: it's getting directly to the catch

Comment: can you show us the reducers ?, think you wrong at the payload

Comment: hav you tried in postman?

Comment: I handle the update slightly different , but I double checked the redux side is working fine.

Comment: it works perfectly in postman  but with a 'contentType' header, i tried adding it but nothing changed

Comment: You could try something like Charles Proxy to see the outgoing request as your code send it. From that you can then probably diagnose if there are any payload issues. You can compare to your working Postman test then for any other differences.

Comment: Hi mate, can I see your API_HOST? maybe it have an slash at the end. I've tried your setup and it worked. Can you console.log(response) as well? Also your `token` is a function then it must be `value: token()` right?

Comment: i figured it's something to do with axios defaults, i need to disaable the ssl verification, and it doesn't get any response whatsoever it falls directly to the catch and the error.response is undefined

Comment: also there's no extra slash on the api host, and the exact same one works in postman

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is easy and readable...

```
      axios
        .post(api_url + '/v1/login?', data, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
        .then(
          res => {
            alert('Response');
          },
          error => {
             alert('Error');
          },
        );
    }
  };
```